# linking procedure to button

Tags: tcl, procedure

I have now created the same user interface with initially using a gui builder for tcl.  However, it became limited in terms of how I could structure my interface and the spacing between widgets.  Now that I've created my interface I'm looking to create a procedure block to a specific widget.  For example, I would like the quit button to exit the program.

To achieve this I created the following procedure:

```
proc btnQuit args {
exit
}
```

This doesn't cause a syntax or runtime error however, when the button is pressed, the program does not exit.  This is the simplest case as there are others that are more complex so the -command flag will not apply to all situations.

Thoughts?

Below is my entire code.  This is just bringing up the user interface.

```
#Includes the necessary packages
package require BWidget
package require Tk

namespace eval Main_Menu {}

#DO NOT MODIFY!! Graphical User Interface Code DO NOT MODIFY!!

#Limit the size of window
wm maxsize . 475 180    ;#x-500, y-210
wm minsize . 475 180    ;#x-500, y-210

#[Device name] Test Frame w/ associated check boxes
labelframe .lblfrmSelection     -text "Testable Devices" -padx 1 -relief groove -height 175 -width 200
button .btnDualUTA              -text "Dual UTA" -padx 5 -anchor "center" -justify "center" -padx 3
button .btnTProbe               -text "T-Probe" -padx 5 -anchor "center" -justify "center" -padx 7
button .btnOctal                -text "Octal" -padx 5 -anchor "center" -justify "center" -padx 14
button .btnUniversal            -text "Universal" -padx 5 -anchor "center" -justify "center"
button .btnQuit                 -text "Exit" -padx 5 -anchor "center" -justify "center" -padx 18

#Setup second frame with image label
labelframe .lblfrmHWSetup   -text "Hardware Setup" -padx 1 -relief groove -height 200 -width 175
image create photo          glcomm.gif
label .lblSetup             -text "Image goes here"

#*************** Render User Environment ******************
#Create Device Test Interface with check boxes in frame.
place .lblfrmSelection  -anchor nw -x 5 -y 1 -width 165 -height 175
place .btnDualUTA       -in .lblfrmSelection -x 40 -y 15 -anchor "w" 
place .btnTProbe        -in .lblfrmSelection -x 40 -y 46 -anchor "w" 
place .btnOctal         -in .lblfrmSelection -x 40 -y 76 -anchor "w" 
place .btnUniversal     -in .lblfrmSelection -x 40 -y 106 -anchor "w" 
place .btnQuit          -in .lblfrmSelection -x 40 -y 136 -anchor "w"

#Create label frame "Hardware Setup"
place .lblfrmHWSetup    -anchor nw -x 170 -y 1 -height 175 -width 300
place .lblSetup         -in .lblfrmHWSetup -x 171 -y 2

# MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE!! MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE!!

proc btnQuit args {
exit
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how the button is created, but the `-command` option *is* what you need

```
$ tclsh <<'END'
package req Tk
proc btnQuit args {exit}
button .b -text Quit -command btnQuit
pack .b
END
```

If your button is already created, you can configure it with the -command option

```
button .b -text Quit
.b configure -command btnQuit
```

---

Note that this looks for the "btnQuit" proc in the **global** namespace. If you're using namespaces, you have to fully qualify  the command name. This will throw an error when you click the button (invalid command name "btnQuit")

```
namespace eval MySpace {
    proc btnQuit args {exit}
}
button .b -text Quit -command btnQuit
```

In this case, you need

```
button .b -text Quit -command MySpace::btnQuit
```

---

If you need to pass arguments to the btnQuit proc, you'll do something like

```
button .b -text Quit -command [list btnQuit $local_var1 $local_var2]
```

or

```
button .b -text Quit -command {btnQuit $global_var1 $global_var2}
```

The different quoting mechanisms cause the variables to be substituted at different times:

- the first when the button is created;
- the second when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have provided the code which is my user interface.  What do you mean by in the global namespace?  I don't actually understand what a namespace is even though I have it in my code <-- I copied it from the code created by the GUI builder.

Comment: Looks like all you need is `.btnQuit configure -command btnQuit` after your btnQuit proc

Comment: It doesn't appear to do anything.

proc btnQuit {.btnQuit configure -command btnQuit}

The program does not exit.  I've also tried removing "btnQuit" from the end.

Comment: Of course that does not exit: you took out the exit command. Do this: `proc quit {} {exit}; .btnQuit configure -command quit`

Comment: I just figured it out about an hour ago.  Thanks for working through the problem and glad to see that my extra effort and online searching yielded similar results. :-)